# XML Vs JSON in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I am having a HTML5 application from where I am reading the values in the JS and then creating its XML using Dictionary in class.

I came up with the blog to Consumethe json INTO SQL directly.

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

Please let me know the cost wise views If I moves to the JSON approach leaving the XML behind.

Thanks

Comment: My suggestion is to serialize objects AFTER they're read from SQL Server. Not to use SQL Server as serializer. I'd prefer to use the middle layer cpu instead of the one of the SQL Server Instance. This because in SQL Server 2012, JSON support is not native (it will in 2016).

Comment: SQL Server is now supporting JSON on SQL Server 2016. From SQL to JSON is being supported since first CTP release. From JSON to SQL data will be supported with CTP3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are thinking performance wise parsing of XML and JSON is not much difference. There are typical use cases where both of these are fit.

Advantages of XML:

- There's already an industry standard XSD to follow.
- Validation afforded by creating a new XSD is important to you or your callers.
- You need to transform the data to another XML form. (XSLT works wonders for transformations.)
  Or, you have to represent mixed content (tags mixed within text).

Choose JSON if

- The closer fit to JavaScript is valuable to you or your callers.
- You prefer a lighter-weight solution.
- Or, the reasons mentioned above for choosing XML do not apply to you.

For more information go through the blog link [JSON Vs XML](https://blogs.oracle.com/xmlorb/entry/analysis_of_json_use_cases)